# html5 and heat sensors

Tags: iphone, html, sensors, heat

I'm new to html5 programming and was thinking of building an html5 app for iphone. I was wondering if there was any information in the API about sensing temperature on touch in the api? My app depends on the temperature of ones finger when they touch the screen. Is there anyway to measure this? IF not, is there a way to measure the amount of pressure applied to the screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Room temperature: Yes.

The temperature of your thumb on the iPhone screen: no.

The pressure of your thumb on the screen: also no.

Remember - the iPhone "touch" works on *capacitance*, not "mechanical pressure".

Comment: PS: Of course, maybe you *can* write an app that measures your psychic aura when you press the screen ;)

Comment: Room temperature: No. Die temperature: With jailbreak.

Comment: Thanks! All of these answers were very helpful!

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta sorry, what do you mean by die temperature?

Comment: @Jessica: temperature of the [CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_(integrated_circuit)), used to shut down the iPhone in case of overheating.